# IsNullOrEmpty with an empty value still go into the loop

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently trying to compare in `C#` a value I get from my `database`, and i use "IsNullOrEmpty" to check if the value is, well, null or empty.

When the value in the `database` is "null", no problem.

However, when the value is "empty", I still enter the loop;

I add an empty value:

```
  update Planning
  set Repas2 =''
  where jour = '01/11/19' and Matricule='601'
```

And now the debug :

[image]

as you can see, "Repas2" is empty but I still go in the loop.

Anyone know why I'm doing this?

Comment: Looks like it's a single space rather than an empty string

Comment: It looks like it's not empty. It contains a space.

Comment: not shure but I think it´s not empty its whitespace

Comment: Yeah but when i use "  set Repas2 ='' ", there is no space

Comment: Why store an empty string, or just a <space>?

Comment: ' ' is not a valid string in c#  please post your real code

Comment: I check what is recorded by customers, who  (wrongly) put empty fields. I don't want to store empty field, i just did it to show my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(...)` instead